# Bash grep/echo replacing n with whitespace

Tags: bash

I'm composing a small script to cron hourly to check our Ironport logs for internal staff sending spam. This snippet is resulting in some weird behaviour where n characters (NOT newlines) are replaced with whitespace, e.g.

> Nov 12 17:17:27 [sanitized] 1 textmail-[sanitized]: I fo: MID 2417158 i terim verdict usi g e gi e: CASE spam positive

Code:

```
VAR=`egrep $line /var/spam_checker/log_temp`
# extract email address from that variable
echo -e $VAR >> /var/spam_checker/debug
```

NB. This is a snippet of code - there is a reason why it's stored in a variable rather than writing to a file

Am I missing a switch for the egrep/echo or something?

Comment: Try `echo` without the `-e` option. This might help as `-e` tries to translate escape sequences.

Comment: Also put doublequotes around `$VAR` in case it contains special shell characters.

Comment: and put dbl-quotes around `"$line"`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your all your input guys. Sakthi: the -e was left in when I was debugging another issue. Barmar: spot on - that's fixed it, thanks! (Are you able to use the "answer question" rather than "comment" so I can give you credit for this?) Choroba & Shellter - thinking along the same lines - thanks for your input, I'll take a closer look at what $line contains too

Answer (score 2):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

Also put double quotes around `$VAR` in case it contains special shell characters. – Barmar

```
echo -e "$VAR" >> /var/spam_checker/debug
```